# Gateway in the branch of another gateway

Tags: adobe, livecycle

In the setup of an e-form. We require a gateway in the branch of another gateway. However i'm not getting this to work properly. Is this possible? How do I achieve this?

What i have is the following:

My first gateway has 2 branches. Of which the first branch is an approval task. After this approval task, the form needs to be sent to a certain emailaddress **without waiting** on the other branch.

In the second branch. I have another gateway with 8 branches which each contain an approval task. These tasks **DO have to wait** for each other to be completed before sending the email.

So this is why I would need these 2 gateways.

However when i implement this and test it the recording stops just in front of the second gateway without any error message.

Any ideas how to fix/implement this?

---

Images:

### Gateway 1

[image: gateway 1]

### Gateway 2 (in Other Approvals Process):

[image: gateway 2]

Both have all branches setup synchronous:

[image: branch settings]

When I Playback the recording for "Other Approvals", the process seems to stop before entering the second gateway:

[image: playback]

---

Apparently i seem to get following error now:

```
    Cannot execute a split on transactional branch.
StackTrace: 
com.adobe.idp.dsc.DSCRuntimeException: Cannot execute a split on transactional branch.
    at com.adobe.idp.workflow.dsc.invoker.WorkflowDSCInvoker.transientInvoke(WorkflowDSCInvoker.java:324)
    at com.adobe.idp.workflow.dsc.invoker.WorkflowDSCInvoker.invoke(WorkflowDSCInvoker.java:158)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationInterceptor.intercept(InvocationInterceptor.java:140)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.DocumentPassivationInterceptor.intercept(DocumentPassivationInterceptor.java:53)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:74)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.execute(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:357)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.doRequiresNew(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor215.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359)
    at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:404)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
    at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:960)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invoke(BaseLocalProxyFactory.java:430)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.StatelessSessionProxy.invoke(StatelessSessionProxy.java:103)
    at $Proxy167.doRequiresNew(Unknown Source)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.EjbTransactionProvider.execute(EjbTransactionProvider.java:143)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:72)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationStrategyInterceptor.intercept(InvocationStrategyInterceptor.java:55)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvalidStateInterceptor.intercept(InvalidStateInterceptor.java:37)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.AuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:188)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.JMXInterceptor.intercept(JMXInterceptor.java:48)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.engine.impl.ServiceEngineImpl.invoke(ServiceEngineImpl.java:115)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.routing.Router.routeRequest(Router.java:129)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.base.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:93)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.vm.VMMessageDispatcher.doSend(VMMessageDispatcher.java:225)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.base.AbstractMessageDispatcher.send(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:66)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.clientsdk.ServiceClient.invoke(ServiceClient.java:208)
    at com.adobe.idp.jobmanager.execution.workadapter.AbstractExecutableJob.invokeRequest(AbstractExecutableJob.java:127)
    at com.adobe.idp.jobmanager.execution.workadapter.PersistentExecutableJob.execute(PersistentExecutableJob.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.workmanager.adapter.UnManagedAsynchronousWorkAdapter.run(UnManagedAsynchronousWorkAdapter.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resource.work.WorkWrapper.execute(WorkWrapper.java:204)
    at org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.run(BasicTaskWrapper.java:275)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:743)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you give some more information on the scenario you are testing?

Comment: added some extra info. Hope it helps?

Comment: Do you see all the approval tasks to be created? If so can you try running the process recording after completing all the tasks.

Comment: The SAP approval taks (in the first gateway) is created, the others aren't being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue!

Apparently my subprocess "Other Approvals" was still configured as a short-lived process. This caused the flow to generate a Fatal error.

By adding an approval task to the process, the process was automatically converted to a long-lived process. Afterwards I removed the approval task. And redeployed the application. This solved the issue and made the flow work.